# extracting strings between 2 chars - all occurrences

Tags: c#, string, split

I would like to do something like this:

My string example: "something;123:somethingelse;156:somethingelse2;589:somethingelse3"

I would like to get an array with values extracted from the string example. These values lies between ";" and ":" : 123, 156, 589

I have tried this, but I do not know how to iterate to get all occurrences:

```
string str = stringExample.Split(';', ':')[1];
string[i] arr = str;
```

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: `Split` returns an *array*; so you can loop as you want, e.g. `foreach(string item in stringExample.Split(';', ':')) {...}`

Comment: The problem is that you are specifying the index after you are splitting. Remove the `[1]` and then `str` will be a `string[]`

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is your friend here, something like this would do:

```
str.Split(';').Select(s => s.Split(':')[0]).Skip(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression like this:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@";(\d+):");
string s = "something;123:somethingelse;156:somethingelse2;589:somethingelse3";
foreach(Match m in r.Matches(s))
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
```

`;(\d+):` matches one or more digits standing between `;` and `:` and `Groups[1]` selects the content inside the brackest, ergo the digits.

Output:

```
123
156
589
```

To get these strings into an array use:

```
string[] numberStrings = r.Matches(s).OfType<Match>()
                          .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                          .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would work with named groups:

```
string stringExample = "something;123:somethingelse;156:somethingelse2;589:somethingelse3";
Regex r = new Regex(";(?<digit>[0-9]+):");
foreach (Match item in r.Matches(stringExample))
{
    var digit = item.Groups["digit"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to extract all 3 numbers, you could use this approach:

```
string stringExample = "something;123:somethingelse;156:somethingelse2;589:somethingelse3";
string[] allTokens = stringExample.Split(';', ':'); // remove [1] since you want the whole array
string[] allNumbers = allTokens.Where(str => str.All(Char.IsDigit)).ToArray();
```

Result is:

```
allNumbers  {string[3]} string[]
            [0] "123"   string
            [1] "156"   string
            [2] "589"   string
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect case for a regular expression.

```
    var sample = "something;123:somethingelse;156:somethingelse2;589:somethingelse3";
    var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=;)(\d+)(?=:)");
    var matches = regex.Matches(sample);

    var array = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```